# How do you call the minimal strict upper bound (similar to supremum but with strict order)

Tags: order-theory

Given a set $A \subset \mathbb{K}$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is a partially ordered set $(\mathbb{K}, \leq)$, the supremum is $\sup{A} = \min\{b\in\mathbb{K}|\forall a \in A: a \leq b\}$. Is there a name for something like $\overset{\sim}{sup} := \min\{b\in\mathbb{K}|\forall a \in A: a \lt b\}$?

For example, with $\mathbb{K} := \mathbb{N}$, $A := \{3, 4, \dots 12\}$, it would be $\overset{\sim}{sup}{A} = 13$.

Another example would be $\mathbb{K} := \mathbb{R}$, $A := \arctan[\mathbb{R}]$ (the image), it’s $\overset{\sim}{sup}{A} = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

It doesn’t always exist though, for example, with $\mathbb{K} := \mathbb{R}$, $A := [3, 13]$. (In $\mathbb{R}$, the supremum is either the maximum or the $\overset{\sim}{sup}$, so only either of the two exists)

For integers, the concept is similar to the upper bound used in `for` loops which is the number next to the maximum of the relevant set.

Comment: There is no established term, your "minimal strict upper bound" is as good as any. Note also that not only may it not exist but in partially ordered sets there may be multiple ones.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. With “multiple ones” are you thinking about the incomparable case? An interesting point, but the definition of supremum also seems to require the comparability of all members of $A$ with every upper bound $b_i$ ($\forall a \in A: b_i \leq a \lor a \leq b_i$) as well as the upper bounds among themselves (you can’t find the minimum otherwise). Under this restriction, uniqueness appears to hold for my $\overset{\sim}{sup}$ as well because it only further narrows down the set of upper bounds.

Comment: Supremum is the least majorant and every set $S\subseteq \mathbb R$ has a supremum and infimum in $\overline{\mathbb R}$

Comment: Supremum does not require comparability. In partially ordered sets it may not exist, but if "the least" exists it is unique by anti-reflexivity. You could take "the least strict upper bound" but that may not exist even in linearly ordered sets when supremum does.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks again, yes, the actual question was already answered by your first comment and it seems like my understanding of a supremum in a set with incomparable elements is insufficient to grasp what you’re saying about the lack of uniqueness, but this is of a rather secondary relevance to the question anyway