# A property of partitions of the real numbers

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, order-theory

Let a *strict linear order* $C = (V, <)$, be an irreflexive and transitive relation < defined on $V$, and call a *section* of $C$ a partition of $V$ into two sets $A, B$, such that $x < y$, whenever $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. The strict linear order $C$ is called *continuous* if all sections of the $C$ are such that either 1. or 2. hold:

1. $A$ has a maximal element (i.e, $\exists z \in A (\forall x \in A (x < z))$) and $B$ doesn't have a minimum element (i.e, $\neg \exists z \in B (\forall x \in B (z < x))$).
2. $A$ doesn't have a maximal element and $B$ has a minimum element.

I have read that a fundamental example of a continuous strict linear order is the real numbers under the relation of inequality. I can't see how any partition of the reals into two sets either satisfies condition 1. or condition 2. above. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Yes it is equivalent.

Comment: In a linear order a maximal element is the same as the maximum. And if $A$ and $B$ are the two blocks of a partition, then $A\cap B = \varnothing$ and $A\cup B=\mathbb R$; thus, if $A$ has a maximum, then $B$ cannot have a minimum.

Comment: I mis-stated condition 1. It has now been corrected.

Comment: @amrsa I am not defining a strict linear order as a total order (I.e, a type of partial order). I have just specified my definition in the question. I simply mean an irreflexive and transitive relation defined on a set

Comment: You definition must be wrong. $(P \wedge Q)\vee(\neg P\wedge Q)\equiv Q$. So you say that the order is continuous iff $C=A \cup B$ with $B$ having a minimum element. But that is true for any (non-empty) order: pick $b \in C$ and define $A=\{x\in C: x<b\}$ and $B=\{x\in C: x\geq b\}$.

Comment: @amrsa It's $(P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P \land Q)$. I changed it before

Comment: Ok, was that one of your edits? I thing you've done quite a few :)

Comment: Yes it was my edit.

Comment: So it's now clear that it works in $\mathbb R$, right?

Comment: No. If you write it up in an answer it would be appreciated, since I am not a mathematician

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the required conditions, you have $A\cup B = \mathbb R$ with $A\cap B=\varnothing$, and $a<b$, whenever $a\in A$ and $b \in B$.

It follows that $\bigvee A = \bigwedge B$ (the supremum of $A$ is the infimum of $B$).
Call this element $c$.

If $c \in A$, then the partition satisfies the first condition.
Otherwise, $c \in B$ and the partition satisfies the second condition.

Comment: This is really clear, thanks :). The only thing is, how do you prove that $\bigvee A = \bigwedge B$? Also, in a strict linear order as I have defined it, does the notion of a maximal element and a supremum coincide, and the notion of a minimal element and a infimum coincide?

Comment: I don't know. But also, are you assuming that a maximal element of $A$ is the same as the supremum of $A$ and the minimal element of $B$ is the same as the infimum of $B$ and if so, why? So the supremum and infimum are always defined for sets of reals?

Comment: You mean $\bigvee$ with respect to the relation $\leq$, not the relation $<$. For the least upper bound of $A$ with respect to $<$ cannot itself be in $A$

Comment: @user65526 Sorry. You are right. It's not the same and I was imprecise. But under the conditions stipulated above, we have $a\leq c \leq c' \leq b$ whenever $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Again, suppose $d=(c+c')/2$; then $c<d<c'$, whence $d\notin A$ and $d\notin B$. Concerning your claim that "the least upper bound of $A$ with respect to $<$ cannot itself be in $A$", I think you're wrong, and it's the same for $<$ or $\leq$, but if it isn't, then what is the definition?

Comment: If $c$ is the supremum of $A$ with respect to $<$ and $c \in A$, then $a< c$, for every $a \in A$, and so $c < c$. But that is impossible. So if $c$ is the supremum of $A$ with respect to $<$ then $c \not\in A$. How do you get from $d = (c + c') / 2$ to $c < d < c'$?

Comment: @user65526 If $c<c'$ then $c'=c+\delta$, for some $\delta>0$ (actually, $\delta=c'-c$). Then $$\frac{c+c'}{2}=c+\frac{\delta}{2}>c,$$ and $$\frac{c+c'}{2}=c'-\frac{\delta}{2}<c'.$$

Comment: Ok, but how can $c$ be the supremum of $A$ with respect to $<$ and also be in $A$, given what I said above.

Comment: @user65526 Either you accept that the definition of supremum (and infimum) is the same for $<$ as it is for $\leq$, or you end up with $\mathbb R$, for example, not being complete, which is undesirable. For example, what would be the supremum of $[0,1]$? It couldn't be $1$ since it belongs to the set; and it can't be some $\delta>1$, as we would get $\alpha=1-(1-\delta)/2$ an element satisfying $\alpha<\delta$ and $x<\alpha$ for $x\in[0,1]$. So the set wouldn't have a supremum and $\mathbb R$ wouldn't be complete.

Comment: I think you are missing my point. My point is that it is impossible for there to be a $c \in A$ which is the supremum of $A$ with respect to $<$. I don't understand what you are saying in response to this impossibility. Are you saying that it is actually impossible, and that I am wrong?

Comment: What I said is that with that definition of supremum, some set which have one (all those that usually have a supremum belonging to it), will no longer have a supremum. You can accept the definition of supremum as being the same as with $\leq$ or you will loose a lot. For more about this, perhaps you should post another (separate) question, but notice it's not very likely to have a more satisfying answer than this; [check this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490944/how-do-you-call-the-minimal-strict-upper-bound-similar-to-supremum-but-with-str).

Comment: Ok, I think things are finally clear. I was reading a chapter on orderings and supremums and infimums defined via them and so got confused, but here you are thinking of the supremum and infimum as (I take it) they would usually be understood as defined on the real numbers.